# I cant login to latest mautic installation, login fails

Tags: mautic

I upgraded the mautic with composer to latest version and I want to login but I get
Invalid login. Please verify credentials.

I am using ddev to develop locally
SO I tried db / db for login...nothing works
the username and pass are stores in local.php if I am not mistaken...?

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

The username and password are not stored in local.php but rather in the users table inside mysql db.

In order to reset it you should login to mysql and connect to your mautic database and run the following commands:

```
Type this command: sudo mysql -u root
This will log you into mysql,
then type: show databases;
This will show you your databases, usually Mautic default install uses DB name mautic,
Type: use mautic; (you can replace the name of the database if you have a different name)
Type: select id, username from users;
This will give you a list of users
Type: UPDATE users SET password = “a5b253d8484925a3b4fba260768416dfdcbeaed639bb3435c566cbf54721f846903725c7283cf9ab1f090f179d015f46a50b5e798695547eda6e2342db8918a2” where id = 1; make sure you are using the id of the user you want to update.
```

You should then be able to login with password 12345678